# How to restore default WebViewClient in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any way to restore a default `WebViewClient` in `WebView`?

There is a `WebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client)` method, but no `get` companion.

I would like to to load URL in WebView and avoid being sent to native browser in case of redirections but then go back to default behavior - links clicked opening in native browser.

To achieve that I would like set my own WebViewClient temporarily and then restore the default one.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
// TODO: restore default WebViewClient
```

Comment: means u want to open any url (with in app) in web view instead of browser

Comment: yes, but then any click should lead to the native browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to go back to the default behavior try:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(null);
```

however you can't do that immediately after you call loadUrl, you need to at least wait for WebViewClient.onPageFinished.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.setWebViewClient(null);
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```